# Xcart upgrade from 4.6.2 to 4.7.5

Tags: upgrade, x-cart

I am trying to upgrade my Xcart 4.6.2 to 4.7.5.  I followed the documentioan exactly as mentioned here http://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Upgrading#Upgrading_from_version_4.7.0_or_later

However the software is updated and the db remains the same.  I said because when I check http://wwww.example/VERSION it says 4.7.5 and when I check http://www.example.com/include/version.php it says X-Cart DB Version: 4.6.2 GOLD.

I did the following steps :

1. made a development copy of live site in server.
2. made a fresh installation of the xcart 4.6.2 and pointed the db to the development copy
3. Downloaded the 4.6.2-4.7.2 upgrade package, extracted it to the root and ran the upgrade from backend.  No errors.
4. I checked http://wwww.example.com/VERSION it says 4.7.2 and http://www.example.com/include/version.php it says X-Cart DB Version: 4.6.2 GOLD

Do you guys faced such issue? Your advises are very much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely something goes wrong while applying the sql patch (upgrade/4.6.2-4.7.2/patch.sql) because

UPDATE xcart_config SET `value` = "4.7.2" WHERE `name` = "version";

is at the very end of it.

So, please, check the following logs for anything out of the ordinary:

var/upgrade/4.6.2-4.7.2/patch.log

var/log/x-errors_sql-.php